# Integrate Ajax content in your custom module in DNN's Search Index using SearchModuleBase?

Tags: search, dotnetnuke

We have a custom Product Detailed View module which will retrieve product data when a query string in the URL contains a certain SKU and navigated from the product filter module page. When the Detailed Product View module loads, it will check for a query string and load the data via Ajax.

I want to integrate DNN's SearchModuleBase so that the custom modules data will show in our custom Search Results module.

I have looked at the SearchModuleBase Wiki and Introduction: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/modulesearchbase

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154913/integrating-with-search-introducing-modulesearchbase

How can I specify the exact content I want DNN's crawler to index?
For example: SKU, Page Title, Product Description?

I would also like to know how you can submit Meta Keywords from the product Object as Tags in the code-behind which can be used for search results?

All the sites I have looked at uses the old ISearchable class: http://www.adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/ISearchable/

This is the current code I have, but I think it is too basic and does not specify the Product Description, SKU and the Page Title:

```
   public class ProductDetailedViewModuleBase : ModuleSearchBase
        {
            public override IList<SearchDocument> GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDateUtc)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

I have changed the manifest file to be searchable. I had to change ISearchable, IPortable and IUpgradeable to Searchable, Portable and Upgradeable.

[image]

I am also trying to add the SearchModuleBase but I am missing something:
[image]

This is the front end code for generating the product info:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code stub you have for `GetModifiedSearchDocuments` is just that.  It's not fully implemented.  You have to replace `throw new NotImplementedException()` with the code to populate the list of `SearchDocument` objects you will return.  The `SearchDocument`'s properties are where you assign the values for the data you want the crawler to index.

```
 public override IList<SearchDocument> GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDateUtc)
 {
     var searchDocs = new List<SearchDocument>();
     var productList = GetProductList();  //you write this method to return a list of your products
     foreach(var product in productList)
     {
         var searchDoc = new SearchDocument
         {
             IsActive = true,
             CultureCode = moduleInfo.CultureCode,
             ...
             Title = product.YourProductName,
             Description = product.YourProductDescription,
             Body = product.YourProductDescription,
         };
         searchDocs.Add(searchDoc);
     }
     return searchDocs;
 }
```

The part where you say:

> I am also trying to add the `SearchModuleBase`, but I am missing something

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you don't need to make any changes there to get your custom content indexing.

Answer (score 2):

The fully-qualified class and namespace that you indicated in your manifest as your **businessControllerClass** is the one that implements ModuleSearchBase.

I should see something like this:

```
namespace MyModule.Modules.ProductDetailedView.Components
{
    public class FeatureController : ModuleSearchBase
    {
        public override IList<SearchDocument> GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDateUtc)
        {
            // TODO: convert your Product info object list to a SearchDocument object list and return
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have this method compiled and implemented, you can go to Settings > Schedule and run the "Site Crawler" schedule task.  Attach your debugger to the DNN process and when the task executes, your GetModifiedSearchDocuments method should get hit.

For a complete tutorial with sample code on this topic, you can subscribe to [dnnhero.com](https://www.dnnhero.com) and check out [my complete search tutorial](https://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/ArticleID/307/Search-Integration-Implement-SearchModuleBase-Part-3-4).